# Combine table cells from from different tables

Tags: html, css

is it possible to combine cells from different tables using CSS?

```
div {
    width:35px;
}
td {
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    display:inline-block;
}

<div>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>6</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/m2rwatob/3/

I need to remove these empty spaces
https://i.stack.imgur.com/76e1v.png

Comment: What spaces are you talking about ? Increase your `div` width in the CSS and you'll see a 3x3 grid.

Comment: How do plan to get a 2x2 grid with 9 elements ? Maybe edit your post with an image of the expected layout.

Comment: The OP is talking about the blank spaces the third TD creates, because it goes in new row because of the width of the div.

Comment: then you should avoid using tables and float the elements..

Comment: i update link to jsfiddle, and add image

Comment: no you cant get this with the existing html and css structure..

Comment: I think you need like. http://jsfiddle.net/m2rwatob/6/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not possible. The most you can do is to combine cells of different rows, by setting `tr {display:inline;}`

See updated fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/m2rwatob/5/

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to combine the tables.
The empty spaces between the tables can be removed with the following CSS style

```
table {
   border-spacing: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No need of css better to use `cellspacing="0"` in table element.

```
<div>
<table cellspacing="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<table cellspacing="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>7</td>
            <td>8</td>
            <td>9</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can remove empty space in following way:

```css
div {
    width:35px;
}
td {
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div>
<table cellspacing="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<table cellspacing="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Hope it helps.